# Formula after inference with bussproof package

Tags: logic, bussproofs

Is it possible obtain a formula as in the picture with bussproof?[image]

I tried with

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
$\mathscr{F} \cup \{\textbf{B}A \wedge (\neg \textbf{B}\neg C) \rightarrow D:$
\AxiomC{$A:C$}
\UnaryInfC{$D$}
$\in \mathscr{D}$ 
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}`

but it doesn't work: last formula appears before the inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inline entry with `\DisplayProof`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{F} \cup \{\textbf{B}A \wedge (\neg \textbf{B}\neg C) \rightarrow D:\AxiomC{$A:C$}\UnaryInfC{$D$}\DisplayProof\in \mathscr{D}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou...And in order to have the formula not inline but in display, I used 
$$ 
`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
$$\mathscr{F} \cup \{\textbf{B}A \wedge (\neg \textbf{B}\neg C) \rightarrow D:\AxiomC{$A:C$}\UnaryInfC{$D$}\DisplayProof\in \mathscr{D}$$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. 
\end{document}`